# Why are there non-breaking spaces in my page title?

Tags: javascript, http

I'm injecting a script via JSONP and using it to call a method in my web application like so:

```
(function jsonp(src){
    var b = document.body;
    var t = document.title;
    var u = encodeURI(document.location.href);

    var o = document.getElementById('srv-call');
    o && b.removeChild(o);

    var s = document.createElement('script');   
    s.id = 'srv-call';
    s.src = src + '?w=' + textSelection + '&cb=autoCall&u=' + u + '&pt=' + t + '&t=' + (new Date().getTime());
    b.appendChild(s);
})('http://localhost:8888/wordmark/words/add_word');
```

Unfortunately, my document.title is getting filled with non-breaking spaces. An example http request is this:

```
http://localhost:8888/wordmark/words/add_word?w=problems&cb=autoCall&u=http://www.boingboing.net/2010/10/01/kid-demonstrates-eng.html&pt=%E2%80%8BK%E2%80%8Bi%E2%80%8Bd%E2%80%8B%20%E2%80%8Bd%E2%80%8Be%E2%80%8Bm%E2%80%8Bo%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8Bs%E2%80%8Bt%E2%80%8Br%E2%80%8Ba%E2%80%8Bt%E2%80%8Be%E2%80%8Bs%E2%80%8B%20%E2%80%8BE%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8Bg%E2%80%8Bl%E2%80%8Bi%E2%80%8Bs%E2%80%8Bh%E2%80%8B%20%E2%80%8Bl%E2%80%8Ba%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8Bg%E2%80%8Bu%E2%80%8Ba%E2%80%8Bg%E2%80%8Be%E2%80%8B%20%E2%80%8Bi%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8B%20%E2%80%8B2%E2%80%8B4%E2%80%8B%20%E2%80%8Ba%E2%80%8Bc%E2%80%8Bc%E2%80%8Be%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8Bt%E2%80%8Bs%E2%80%8B%20%E2%80%8B-%E2%80%8B%20%E2%80%8BB%E2%80%8Bo%E2%80%8Bi%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8Bg%E2%80%8B%20%E2%80%8BB%E2%80%8Bo%E2%80%8Bi%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8Bg&t=1285982312594
```

The script that is injected in the page has the correct src, but the HTTP request is incorrect. Any idea why these are being inserted and if I have any way to avoid this, other than parsing them out via regex?

Thanks so much for any help you can give.

Comment: Why are you passing your current page title to the link you are pointing to?

Comment: Hey Sebastian, I'm getting a word from another page and passing it to my web application, where it's inserted in a database. I need to be able to source where the word came from—URL and page title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And I just realized the culprit. I apologize for wasting everyone's time, but in the event anyone else runs across this problem, the issue was the SMRT Safari Extension to alter Safari's URL auto-complete feature. -1 for me for not disabling all extensions and trying multiple browsers. Thanks, all.

Comment: +1 for posting the response and documenting an obscure issue that Google will be able to answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `decodeURIComponent(t)` instead of just `t`?

```
s.src = src + '?w=' + textSelection + '&cb=autoCall&u=' + u + '&pt=' + decodeURIComponent(t) + '&t=' + (new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even when using decodeURIComponent, I get the same URL in the HTTP request.

Comment: That's because you are putting spaces in the url and they are being encoded by the browser.  It's OK, the server you are requesting to will decode them itself, and it will see your title as it is.

Comment: So I would expect something like `Kid%20demonstrates%20English%20language%20in%2024%20accents%20-%20Boing%20Boing` once I encoded this, but it's not doing this. It's placing zero-width spaces between **every single** character. Am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is take the variable t off in your line that says

```
s.src = src + '?w=' + textSelection + '&cb=autoCall&u=' + u + '&pt=' + t + '&t=' + (new Date().getTime());
```

so your link would look something like this instead:

http://localhost:8888/wordmark/words/add_word?w=problems&cb=autoCall&u=http://www.boingboing.net/2010/10/01/kid-demonstrates-eng.html&&t=1285982312594

and if you must have the t variable then insert it into the line like so

```
....(code before) '&pt=' + decodeURIComponent(t) + (code after)......
```

Hope this helps. thanks

**PK**

Comment: I do need to pass the title as a query string, so I can't simply remove it, and I'm not having any luck with decodeURIComponent, either. Any other ideas? Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not non-breaking spaces, but [zero-width spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) (U+200B). They are normally not visible, and may be present in the original title (for text wrapping, or whatever other reason).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Piet. They seem to be present on most pages I'm trying, and I've no idea why. This makes sense as it's being inserted as `\u200b` in my database. Do I have options for removing this?